# Problems with numerical integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics

I tried to plot beam intensity using a function that evaluates a numerical integral, but it didn't work.

Here is my code, which did not produce a result.

```
a1 = 0.6328*10^-6; 
k = (2*π)/a1;
w = 0.02;
c = 0.02; 
m = 1; 
a = 800; 
z = 1000;

M1[x_, r1_, r2_] = 
  NIntegrate[
    Sum[k^2*z^(-2)*BesselJ[m, a *r1]*BesselJ[m, a* r2]*
       BesselJ[b, k* r1* x/z]*BesselJ[b, k* r2* x/z]*
       BesselI[m + b, 2*r1*r2*c^(-2)]*
       Exp[-(c^(-2) + w^(-2))*(r1^2 + r2^2) + (I*k) / 
         (2*z)*(r2^2 - r1^2)]*r1*r2, 
       {r1, 0, ∞}, {r2, 0, ∞}], 
    {b, -∞, ∞}];
a1 = Table[{x, Abs[M1[x]]}, {x, -0.02, 0.02, 0.001}];
ListPlot[a1, PlotRange -> All] TimeUsed[]
```

Here is how appears in my notebook:

[image]

Comment: Welcome on Mathematica.StackExchange. Please always provide copyable code in `InputForm`. This can be done by: (i) marking the code to copy (ii) right click (iii) selecting "Copy As" -> "Input Text".

Comment: Your first problem is that you define `M1[x_,r1_,r2_]=` but then you use `M1[x]`. I am guessing you want to change your function definition to `M1[x_]:=` so that your `r1` and `r2` don't disagree with your `r1` and `r2` variables of integration.

Comment: I'm sorry ,I have changed the error.

Answer (score 1):

*(Not an answer, extended comment.)*

Please experiment with your sum, say, like this:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 Block[{b = 1000, s = 100}, 
  Total@Flatten@
    Table[k^2*z^(-2)*BesselJ[m, a*r1]*BesselJ[m, a*r2]*
      BesselJ[b, k*r1*x/z]*BesselJ[b, k*r2*x/z]*
      BesselI[m + b, 2*r1*r2*c^(-2)]*
      Exp[-(c^(-2) + w^(-2))*(r1^2 + r2^2) + (I*k)/(2*z)*(r2^2 - 
           r1^2)]*r1*r2, {r1, 0, s}, {r2, 0, s}]]
 ]

 (* {0.35228, 0. + 0. I} *)
```

I get zeroes for all 5-6 values of `b` I tried.

Comment: Thank you.this expression was from a paper,and I think the author may do some approximation.